# ASP.NET error with authentication mode Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to use Authentication Forms with my ASP.NET project.

I added the following lines in my web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

and when I run my application, I get this error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

Now I don't know much about IIS and configurations. But after doing some research, I gotta make sure the virtual directory that the site is in is marked as a application in IIS. How would I do that ?

Below is a screenshot[image] of what I see in IIS

Comment: Are you running website from VisualStudio or directly from Browser ?

Comment: I am running my website through Visual Studio via 'Start Debugging'

Comment: How many web.config files you have in the website

Comment: Also try to CLEAN the project and rebuild.

Comment: I have 2 web.config files....1 in the root, the other in my Views folder (I am using MVC 4)

Comment: I have tried to clean the project and rebuild, that did not work

Comment: Do you have a backup directory of a previous version stored in the project folder and not excluded from project? It might happen in such a case.

Comment: Thats the problem. Put only one web.config in the root folder only. remove the remaining. It should work.

Comment: See this link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2005/09/12/464196.aspx

Comment: removing the other web.config in my View folder fixed the issue